# Integral with respect to the uniform measure on the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, probability, geometry, measure-theory

I would need a hint to solve the following problem.

Let $d \varphi$ be denote the normalised uniform measure on $\mathbb{S}^{N-1}$, which is the $N-1$ dimensional sphere, where  $N \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. How to prove that, 
for arbitrary non-negative integers, $n_1$, $\ldots$, $n_N$, we have that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{S}^{N-1}} d \varphi \, \, {\big ( \varphi^1 \big )}^{2 n_1} \ldots 
{\big (\varphi^N \big )}^{2 n_N}  = 
\frac{  \Gamma(N/2)}{2^n \Gamma(n + N/2)} \prod_{i=1}^{N} (2n_i - 1)!!,
$$
where $n= n_1 + \ldots + n_N$ and we used the notation $\varphi =( \varphi^1, \ldots, \varphi^N) \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Here $\Gamma(x)$ is the *Gamma function" and  "!!" is the *double factorial*. These objects are defined here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial; 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly
$$
I\cdot\omega_{N-1}\cdot\int_0^\infty r^{2n}\exp\left(-\frac12r^2\right)\,r^{N-1}\,\mathrm{d}r=\prod_{i=1}^N\int_{-\infty}^\infty x_i^{2n_i}\exp\left(-\frac12x_i^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x_i
$$
where $\omega_{N-1}=\dfrac{2\pi^{N/2}}{\Gamma(N/2)}$ is the volume of the standard $\mathbb{S}^{N-1}$ and
$$
I:=-\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\int_{\mathbb{S}^{N-1}} \left(\varphi^1\right)^{2 n_1} \dots 
\left(\varphi^N\right)^{2 n_N}\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{N-1}.
$$
Now you can compute these integrals.

Comment: Thank you. What is $I$ in your text?

Comment: $I$ is your integral in the LHS